# Extract pages from a PDF file using ITextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

Is it possible using IText to copy PDF pages from a full PDF document and return partial document based on a form field name? For example I need to copy the beginning of a pdf document and stop at a certain text field called [STOP_HERE], so whatever contents before this fields need to be extracted, the [STOP_HERE] field could be located on a different page for each document, so using page numbers wouldn't help here.

I searched online and all I can find is a way to copy only form fields from a document but not the whole document elements including images texts with their exact location and style.

Can IText do the job here?

EDIT: More details

[STOP_HERE] is an AcroForms text field which has been placed in a document by the PDF design person to indicate that everything before this element should be copied as is into a different document. The field itself is not important, I don't want to fill or do anything with it, it's just used as a signal to let the document parser stop there and copy all previous (upper) contents, I just don't know how to read all contents (without changing style, contents, etc) before this field.

Comment: *stop at a certain text field called [STOP_HERE]* - by *text field* you mean an AcroForms text field? Having *[STOP_HERE]* in its field name? Or in its content? Copying a selection of pages from a PDF (not XFA form) is no problem in iText(Sharp); I merely don't understand your stop condition; You probably should share a sample PDF.

Comment: [STOP_HERE] is an AcroForms text field which has been placed in a document by the PDF design person to indicate that everything before this element should be copied as is into a different document. The field itself is not important, I don't want to fill or do anything with it, it's just used as a signal to let the document parser stop there and copy all previous (upper) contents, I just don't know how to read all contents (without changing style, contents, etc) before this field .

Comment: *[STOP_HERE] is an AcroForms text field* - is that the name or the content?

Comment: The name of the field

Comment: To be more precise [STOP_HERE] is the name of the field, I could change this whatever easy for me to recognise, I instructed the designer to use it as the name of the Acrofield so I could get it easily using Itextsharp

Comment: Ok, it is possible. I'll write up some details as soon as I have the time

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible using IText to copy PDF pages from a full PDF document and return partial document based on a form field name? For example I need to copy the beginning of a pdf document and stop at a certain text field called [STOP_HERE]

Unfortunately the OP didn't tell whether the page containing the form field [STOP_HERE] is to be included or not. As that is a mere +/-1 matter, though, I simply assumed the page is to be included.

Thus, the task can be implemented like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(srcFile);

AcroFields.Item field = reader.AcroFields.Fields["[STOP_HERE]"];
if (field != null)
{
    int firstPage = reader.NumberOfPages + 1;
    for (int index = 0; index < field.Size; index++)
    {
        int page = field.GetPage(index);
        if (page > 0 && page < firstPage)
            firstPage = page;
    }

    if (firstPage <= reader.NumberOfPages)
    {
        reader.SelectPages("1-" + firstPage);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dstFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
        stamper.Close();
    }
}

reader.Close();
```

The code opens the source file in a `PdfReader` and first looks for the field. If it exists, it iterates over all appearances of that field and determines the earliest page with an appearance of the field. If there is such a page, the code restricts the reader to the pages up to that page and stores this restriction using a `PdfStamper`.

Comment: But what if my document is only one page? and the [STOP_HERE] is in the middle of this page let's say, how do I only copy elements above this field while ignoring all elements placed after?

Comment: Ah. You originally asked for a way *to copy PDF pages*. Thus, I naturally assumed you meant **complete** pages and not mere page parts. Removing content from a page can be somewhat difficult. If it suffices to hide the extra content, one could prepend a clipping path to the page content or even crop the page accordingly. But if the extra content really has to be removed, things are more difficult. In the iText xtra package currently a cleanup utility for redaction-like purposes is under development but it's not perfect yet.